# Show images when hovering a text link

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I come to this website because I have no particular skill in coding. 
I recently launched a website/blog on Wordpress with a few friends. 
We're mainly writing about competitive strategies in the  game called Magic the Gathering. This game is about trading cards.

I would like to know if there's a way to make images of the card appear when a reader is hovering a name of the card.

It has been done on other well-known websites in the community like this one : http://blog.mtgmadness.com/index.php/the-dark-confidant-rhinos-rampaging-in-the-zoo/emanuel-sutor

See how where you hover on "Dark Confidant" the card appears without you needing to click?

Is there any way to "code" it on Wordpress. If yes, how can it be done ? do I need to go premium on Wordpress to access some sort of code I don't have access to ?

I use HTML to code things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being functionality is being driven by a free plugin called [WP MtG-Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mtg-helper/). You will require a privately hosted WP website, not a wordpress.com website to implement this plugin.

Comment: hello and thanks a BUNCH !
So I basically need to go premium right ?

Comment: No, you need to buy private web hosting and set up wordpress, not go premium with wordpress.com. You can't install private plugins.

Comment: Damned. Thanks anyway !